# Google Sheet API with writing permission without Google sign-in

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, google-sheets-api

I am going to build a web page that using Google spreadsheet as a database to read and write, thus I try to implement sheet API for the purpose. I know that in order to grant writing permission, oauth 2.0 should be used for the sheet api. As the database is opened to public and no user data will be used, I would like to skip the Google sign-in. Is there any measure to grant writing permission without Google sign-in?

Comment: Do you want each user to have their own spreadsheet or a single shared spreadsheet for all users?

Comment: single shared spreadsheet for all users

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a single spreadsheet, you need a Google account for your application which will own the spreadsheet. The application users will not have direct access to the spreadsheet from their own Google accounts - you would have to share it with them and I think there is no need for that.

For this scenario, Google want you to create a service account. You can create in in [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/permissions/serviceaccounts). For detailed info, please take a look at the [Google develeopers page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).